# Grid com Laravel 5.3 buscando as foreign keys

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

Olá. Tenho uma aplicação em que preciso montar um grid com todos os dados da tabela `produtos`. Essa tabela tem foreign keys para outras duas tabelas, `grupo` e `subgrupo`. Para montar meu grid, preciso que o array com os produtos tenha o id do grupo e do subgrupo e todas as outras informações contidas em um array.

Meu método no controller:

```
public function grid(){
    return \App\produto::all();
}
```

O model produto tem:

```
public function grupo(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\grupo');
}

public function subgrupo(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\subgrupo');
}
```

Porém não sei como montar o grid usando isso. Preciso que o array de retorno fique mais ou menos assim:

```
[
  {
  "codigo": 3,
  "grupo": [
    {
      "codigo": 1,
      "descricao": "Descrição do grupo"
    }    
  ],
  "subgrupo": [
    {
      "codigo": 1,
      "descricao": "Descrição do subgrupo"
    }
  ],
  "descricao": "1"
  }
]
```

Além disso, como podem notar eu precisei mudar o "id" padrão para "codigo", mas isso já está feito. Mas não sei se isso pode afetar a pesquisa.

Dei uma pesquisada antes mas não encontrei o que precisava, ou talvez não tenha pesquisado a coisa certa por falta de conhecimento dos nomes usados do Laravel. Alguém pode me ajudar, por gentileza?

Comment: Tem como colocar o layout das tabelas, em realmente não entendi!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode trazer pra sua **coleção** os dados do relacionamento através do método `with`do Eloquent ORM. Dá uma olhada [aqui na documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading) para entender melhor.
No seu caso ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
public function grid(){
    return \App\produto::with('grupo', 'subgrupo')->all();
}
```

Lembrando que o que será retornado desta função não é um **array** e sim uma **collection** (`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`). Mas, acredito que já é suficiente para você iterar sobre e realizar as operações que deseja.